# Why is java.io.ObjectStreamException used in WTK stub generator for enums?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit, cldc, jsr172

I am using a web service implemented in WCF which has enums defined in the interface.  I am trying to call this from a Java BlackBerry client.  I am using Eclipse to develop the Java application for BlackBerry.  I am using the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html) (WTK) 2.5.2 to generate stub code since the web service is rather large (already in use by a Windows Mobile client).

When I try generating stub code using the WTK, I get errors in Eclipse about the enums.  In the following function, it complains that java.io.ObjectStreamException cannot be resolved to a type.

```
private Object readResolve()
    throws java.io.ObjectStreamException {
    return fromValue(getValue());
}
```

When running the Stub Generator, there is a switch for either CLDC 1.0 or CLDC 1.1.  Generating with both options result in the same issue.

I found a [forum post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=764788&tstart=690) about this at Sun with no response.  The person in this post states that, "Now java.io.ObjectStreamException is not in CLDC but is in CDC instead. Is there a good tool out there for creating Stubs for Web Services for J2ME specifically CLDC 1.0/1.1 ?"  I verified that it doesn't exist in CLDC 1.1 by looking at the [documentation [3](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/)).

There are two quick fixes available in Eclipse to fix this situation: 1) Create class 'ObjectStreamException' in package 'java.io' or 2) Fix project setup (which is wanting me to add a reference).

Update:

Here is what the JSR-172 specification says...

5.2.5 Enumeration 
The JAX-RPC Subset does not provide support for XML enumerations.

5.2.6 Simple Types Derived By Restriction 
The JAX-RPC Subset does not provide support for deriving simple types by restriction.

The WSDL for the WCF enumeration generates a `<xs:simpleType>` with `<xs:restriction>` containing `<xs:enumeration>`.  So do I just say this field is an int instead and define constants?

Is this just a bug in the WTK?  In case it was, I filed a bug report with Sun and will see if they respond.  Why wouldn't the toolkit flag this as an error?

So now I need to change the interface so that it is JSR-172 compliant.  Are there tools to read WSDL and point out compliancy issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLDC and the Wireless Toolkit both use Java Micro Edition.
JavaME is based on version 2 of the java language, which means no generics and no enums.

The first step in investigating Web Services for your Blackberry handset would be to read the JSR-172 specifications.

Comment: Here is what the JSR-172 specification says...

5.2.5 Enumeration
The JAX-RPC Subset does not provide support for XML enumerations.

5.2.6 Simple Types Derived By Restriction
The JAX-RPC Subset does not provide support for deriving simple types by restriction.

The WSDL for the WCF enumeration generates a <xs:simpleType> with <xs:restriction> containing <xs:enumeration>.  Hmmm...doesn't look like that will work.